# Does an empty array take up space?

Tags: arrays

After looking online, it seems like this depends on the language being used?

However, I couldn't find any place where there was some sort of list with several different programming languages and whether this was true of not for each one.

Could someone confirm this and perhaps list a couple languages where initializing an empty array takes up the same amount of space as if it was filled? and a couple where it doesnt?

So, for example, if I were somehow restricted to only be able to load 1000 integers into memory, could I initialize a 100000 integer empty array (assuming the empty array wouldn't take up the same amount of space as if it were filled)?

Comment: As you say, it depends completely on the language, or rather, on what exactly "array" means (many implementation details differ a lot). So, which language?

Comment: I didn't have a specific language in mind. Studying for interviews and came across a question that lead me to think of this. Java seems to indeed take up space. How about C, Python, C++, C#, JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention...hard (impossible) to answer without a targeted language.

However, languages that use linked-lists to join array elements together are more likely to not pre-allocate memory for undefined elements.

If you need to reduce your memory footprint to minimum (as in your 100000 element example) you could use an add-in library that implements linked lists outside the language of your choice.

Comment: What language uses "linked-lists to join array elements together"? I've never heard of a reputable source trying to sell a linked list of anything as an array. Because it fundamentally isn't, it's on the opposite end of the design spectrum for sequences.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I misspoke saying "array elements"--maybe just "elements" or "list elements".  For example, I was thinking of functional languages like F# that heavily use  singly linked lists in addition to preallocated arrays.  I assume preallocated arrays are in universal use because memory is so plentiful today.  Anyway, "back in the day" (I'm kinda old) we needed to run quality control assessments of very large, but intermittent datum.  We recompiled Cobol (and later Fortran) to use linked lists instead of using fixed arrays.

Comment: But such a list is not an array in any sense of the word, so remarks about them seem completely out of place in this question.

Comment: Ok, you win! :)  Arrays in modern languages almost certainly have preallocated memory.  The questioner is studying for job interviews and -- IMHO -- An interviewer asking "Do arrays always take up memory?"  would like to hear both (1) Most likely yes, and also (2) linked lists could be used for intermittent datum if memory is a concern.

Comment: It's almost trivial to make an empty array make no space (insofar this is possible). Just represent it as the null pointer. Linked lists have rather different advantages, memory usage is not one of them. The next pointer alone makes them much less space efficient, possible back pointers and per-allocation metadata make it even worse; the only "advantage" regarding memory is that they don't need continuous memory and hence work around fragmentation.